# Call to undefined function exit() in PHP

Tags: php, exit

I have the following code

```
<?php
$f = 'exit';
print "function '$f' \n";
$f();
print "end \n";
?>
```

that produce this error message:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function exit()`

Why can find PHP no exit() function? If I replace the `$f();` with a `exit();` it works find.

Br

Comment: Why are you thinking this should work?

Comment: Just in general, I think this is a bad idea. This will make the code horribly hard to maintain by developers coming after you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call the exit function?

Comment: I know this is a bad idea for production systems. This was only a test to explore PHP. Thx for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
eval($f."();");

Its not a nice way but have to work

Comment: This is horribly inefficient, and potentially insecure. The PHP manual even recommends that you NEVER use eval(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: yup, that why i said thas its not a nice way.. But if the only way to do that in the context that he is pointing, of course, there its a logical "problem" if u need to take the eval function as a solution.

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the [PHP manual](http://us.php.net/exit):

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions.

Comment: That sucks! Now I have to do `function callexit($msg){ exit($msg); }`, just so it can work :/